# Print in Table based on condition

Tags: bash

Below is my code for creating the table

```
awk -v server=${svr} 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print "=============================="
printf "<h3>ServerName:%s</h3>", server
print "=============================="
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1">"
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
printf "%s", "<td"
if ($i+0==3) printf " bgcolor=#FF3333"
print ">" $i "
elif print ">" ok " bgcolor=#99FF33"</td>"
}
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
```

Here what i am trying is if $i+0 is 3 then only print the values in table else if non of the value is 3 then it should print $i+0 value as "OK" with a bgcolor.

As you see, i was trying something using elif but doesn't seems to be working.

Please let me know how can it be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing your code more carefully I have fixed following problems in it now.

- Changed line `print ">" $i "` TO `print > "$i"`, else  it may give syntax error not sure you have tested this code or  only written it.
- Added `>` to line `printf "%s", "<td"`.
- Added `</td>`in `if` condition after `bg` value to complete cell of that specific row of table.
- Changed this(`print ">" ok " bgcolor=#99FF33"</td>"`) TO `print "> ok bgcolor=#99FF33</td>"` first I mis-understood that you want to user variable in printing but seems you only want to print statement to console.
- Changed `elif` TO `else` to print correct statement if(`if` statement condition is NOT TRUE).
- Added `'` after `END` BLOCK of `awk` code.
- Mentioned `Input_file` name to code too.
- Fixed formatting of your code for better understanding and making it look nicer :)

---

```
awk -v server=${svr} '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  print "=============================="
  printf "<h3>ServerName:%s</h3>", server
  print "=============================="
  print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1">"
}
{
  printf "<TR>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     printf "%s", "<td>"
     if($i+0==3){
        printf "bgcolor=#FF3333</td>"
        print > "$i"
     }
     else{
        print "> ok bgcolor=#99FF33</td>"
     }
   }
   print "</TR>"
}
END{
   print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Sorry was on leave. came and tested your code.it is giving output like below
`> ok bgcolor=#99FF33
> ok bgcolor=#99FF33
> ok bgcolor=#99FF33`